# Phase noise modelling for simple signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulation, modeling, phase

How to do phase noise modelling for a simple signal? That would be good if anyone can help me.

```
t = 0:0.01:10;
ts = 0.01;
fs = 1/ts;
s = cos(2*pi*10*t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is an additional term inside your `cos` that contains a random error. 
e.g.

```
ns = randn;
s = cos(2*pi*10*t+ns);
```

Is  that all you need? You can scale ns by the magnitude of phase noise. To add more realizations of noise use `ns = randn(n,1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ TheodorBecker. by using rand gives only noise flore. it does not give spreading of spectrum. I am expecting the spreding of spectrum in frequency domain after taking fft.